# How would I solve this trigonometric equation $\ln[(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^{1+\sin(2x)}]=2$?

Tags: trigonometry

How would I simplify this? I can't understand which log property to use to simplify this to get the solution of this trigonometric equation

$$\ln[(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^{1+\sin(2x)}]=2$$

I know that $1+\sin(2x) = (\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2$, but I cant understand which property of logarithms to apply to get the solution here.

Comment: Is this $(\ln(\sin x+\cos x))^{1+\sin(2x)}$, or $\ln\left((\sin x+\cos x)^{1+\sin (2x)}\right)$ ?

Comment: @Gae.S. the exponent is only for sinx + cosx not for the natural log as a whole

Comment: @Techie5879 Could you verify the edit I just made to the brackets?

Answer (score 3):

The equation can be written as:

$$t^{t^2}=e^2$$

where $t = \sin x+\cos x$. The function $f:(0,\sqrt{2}]\to \mathbb{R}, f(t)=t^{t^2}$, has one local minimum at $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$, so:

$$f(t)\leq \max \{\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x),f(\sqrt{2})\}=f(\sqrt{2})=2<e^2$$

because $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=1$. The equation does not have any solution.

Comment: If I may ask the downvoter, what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: *Welcome to the club of victims of mysterious downvoters* and $\to +1$

Comment: Some teachers die a little inside when they see a  homework problem done out in detail for students to scoop up. The question also asks for a simplification, not a full solution, so that the question was not answered. Not my downvote by the way!

Comment: @Paul, Are you saying an answer along the lines of '$\ln t^{t^2}= 2$ simplifies to $t^{t^2} = e^2$' would be more appropriate? What's the point of misleading when the question is kind of dull (and probably mistyped)?

Answer (score -1):

If we use ln a^b = b ln a then we get (sin x + cos x)^2 ln (sin x + cosx) = 2.............but max value of sin x + cos x is root 2 and if we put that we get ln 2 so I dont think any real solution exists. If you want to solve for unreal solution put cos x = (e^ix + e^-ix)/2 and sin x = (e^ix - e^-ix)/2i.